# How to trigger full screen on web without user gesture/interaction

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am creating a web game that requires to be automatically on full screen on startup but browsers put a security restriction whereby full screen API can only be initiated on user action or gesture
Is there any way I can bypass this?

I have tried every possible way but it keeps saying in console "full screen API can only be initiated by user gesture

Comment: Well **you simply don't**. No user wants their browser to transition into fullscreen mode just because they visit an URL (and it would be a security issue as well, used for phishing etc). Put a button on your web page to start the game.

Answer (score -1):

You really shouldn't- it's designed the way it is for a reason, since it would pose both a security threat and an annoyance to the users that visit the site.

That said, if you make a empty button that makes it fullscreen (say, using an onclick that runs a function to make it fullscreen) and position it and size it so it covers the page, along with setting the opacity as 0 to keep it invisible, any user touching the otherwise blank screen causes fullscreen:

index.html

```
<button onclick="makeItFullScreen()" style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100vw; height: 100vh;" id="fullScreenBtn"></button>
<div id="myDiv" style="background: green; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 0px; height: 0px;">

</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("fullScreenBtn").click();
});

// Placeholder action for the fullscreen function
function makeItFullScreen() {
  document.getElementById('myDiv').requestFullscreen()
}
</script>
```

Comment: "*try using JavaScript to click the button*" - that is not going to work

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: Because code simulating a button click is not a user gesture. The fullscreen API will not accept it. It's designed this way for a reason, and the security is better than being thwarted by such a simple workaround.

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry, I didn't understand the question then. I edited my answer with a better solution. I'm pretty new to StackOverflow.

Comment: *"any user touching"* That's user gesture/interaction.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It was just an option, and was the best I could think of to achieve a somewhat similar result.